# Divergence theorem for fractional Laplacian operator

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm not able to find relevant references on the internet. Is there such theorem or which part fails compared to the usual divergence theorem where we can apply the Laplacian operator $\Delta$?

Update: For those who downvoted, do you know the answer or not?

To be more specific: for the usual divergence theorem, $$\int_{\Omega} u\Delta vdx=\int_{\partial \Omega} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}d\sigma - \int_{\Omega} \nabla u\nabla vdx$$ I was wondering whether it's possible to generalize to fractional laplacian operator.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I wonder could you be more specific to your question? What kind of divergence theorem for fractional Laplacian operator you expect to? Can you write down the formula that you guess?

Comment: @user284331 Just updated the question.